# Approach to handling multiple instances of an application that make large database operations simultaneously

Tags: c#, architecture, oracle

So, essentially the flow of my application works like this:

- A user selects some options to start a process on the server.
- Once they hit submit, on the server it opens up a console application that processes large amounts of data and then exits when it's finished
- The idea being that the user can start multiple processes and have them all run at the same time (due to how the architecture is designed, multi-threading couldn't address this issue).

There are certain parameters that a user can choose that will cause a large insert to occur during the start of the process (something like 1,500,000 records from an external source). Even if there are multiple processes running, but only one of them has the option selected to perform that large insert, the applications perform reasonably well (the insert portion of the process takes roughly 4 minutes). However, if there are at least two instances that require that bulk insert, performance and timing drastically falls (i.e. the applications have been running for half an hour, stuck on the insert).

It might be worth mentioning that I'm doing this through a stored procedure call from the application to an Oracle 11g database.

I don't have very many ideas on how to handle this, but one approach is to check if the procedure is running with a different application, and waiting for the procedure to finish. I'm not sure if this is feasible or even the best approach. Any suggestions or directions for me to research is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code that performs the bulk insert:

```
public void CaptureDataForProcess(int processId)
{
    using (var context = new SomeContext())
    {
        var in_processId = new OracleParameter("in_processId", OracleDbType.Int32, processId, ParameterDirection.Input);

        context.Database.SqlQuery<object>("BEGIN SP_CAPTURE_DATA_FOR_PROCESS(:in_processId); END;", in_processId);
    }
}
```

Also, this is more or less the stored procedure (Since it's just a regular Insert command, I've limited the columns referenced for the sake of brevity):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CAPTURE_DATA_FOR_PROCESS (in_processid IN NUMBER)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        processId NUMBER(38, 0) := in_processid ;

    BEGIN  

        INSERT INTO CURRENT_PROCESS_SNAPSHOTS
            ("MARKET",
            "COUNTY",
            "STATE",
            "VENDOR",
            "PROCESSID")
        SELECT
            "MARKET",
            "COUNTY",
            "STATE",
            "VENDOR",
            processId
        FROM external_source@foo;
    END;
END;
/
```

Comment: how exactly are you performing the bulk insert?

Comment: ok. 1. stop using stored procs immediately. 2. if the sproc does the collection you will have to post it

Comment: when you say external source, do you mean external table? whats the exact setup?

Comment: It's a different server from what the target database is hosted on

Comment: a linked server?

Comment: @Ewan that is correct.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Four min is way too long. You need to split up what you are doing so that the final insert is a single statement with all the data already on the box.

So in general you can follow the following steps, although each DB has its own special bulk operations.

1. Collect all the data before you even talk to the database
2. Insert that data into a temp table that won't lock any other processes
3. Check there are no constraints that will fail for the rows
4. Copy the data over from the temp table to the real table in one go.

Edit

The way you are doing it with a linked database means that the database will be running that select while all the data downloads from the other database.

Bring the data in with an application instead. Following the steps above

Answer (score 1):

> However, if there are at least two instances that require that bulk insert, performance and timing drastically falls (i.e. the applications have been running for half an hour, stuck on the insert).

Based on what info you have provided, it seems likely that the issue you are seeing is related to some sort of lock contention.  There are esoteric logs that you can get out of Oracle that can tell you exactly what kind of lock it is and what the scope of it is but for the sake of this answer, I'm assuming that there's no easy way to resolve this contention safely.  You may want to look into cursor isolation levels, however, in order to see whether you can get away with something less strict.

Without redesigning this, the simplest solution would appear to be introducing a load queue.  If you don't have a queueing system available, you can get away with a table based queue for now.  As long as you only have one process working with that table, it should be fine.  Essentially, you create a table with a sequence, the type load that needs to be done and the status of that load.  Then when the user selects to start a load, you simply add that information to the table.  Then you have a script or small application that polls that table and executes the loads one-by-one.  When it's finished.  At a bare minimum, when it's complete you mark the status column as 'complete'.  You might want to have an in-process state or track other details such as when the request was created, started and finished.

This will eliminate the contention between the loads.  Stepping back, however, you might want to think a little about whether you need to have these records loaded from one DB to the other in the first place as these DBs are linked.  Making copies of these records may not be necessary.